# View of Node revisions exclude first revision of each node

Tags: views, 9

I have a view of Node revisions. I want to only show revisions that are edits. I want to exclude the first revision of each node.

I think filtering for created <> changed would work, but I could find a filter in views, or a contrib module that does this.

Is there a way to do this without writing a custom view filter plugin?

Comment: Couldn't it also be true that the highest revision id is not necessarily the published or current one? Is it possible to query for node revisions whos state is not published?

Comment: I am only looking to exclude the first revision. The publish state, and if it is the current revision or not does not matter to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without writing a custom view filter plugin?

I'm afraid not.

> I am only looking to exclude the first revision.

mymodule/**mymodule.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function mymodule_views_data() {
  $data = [];

  $data['node_revision']['exclude_first_node_revision_filter'] = [
    'title' => t('Exclude first node revision'),
    'help' => t('Excludes the first node revision.'),
    'filter' => ['id' => 'exclude_first_node_revision_filter'],
  ];

  return $data;
}
```

mymodule/src/Plugin/views/filter/**ExcludeFirstNodeRevisionFilter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\FilterPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * @ViewsFilter("exclude_first_node_revision_filter")
 */
class ExcludeFirstNodeRevisionFilter extends FilterPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);

    $this->valueTitle = t('Exclude first node revision');
    $this->definition['options callback'] = [$this, 'generateOptions'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $this->ensureMyTable();

    // Exclude the first revision of each node.
    $this->query->addWhereExpression($this->options['group'], "node_revision.vid <> (SELECT MIN(vid) FROM {node_field_revision} WHERE nid = node_revision.nid)");
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function adminSummary() {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function operatorForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function canExpose() {
    return FALSE;
  }

}
```